# maven multimodule build: package vs. install

Tags: maven

What is the true way of building multi-module maven project: via `package` or via `install` if **NONE** of the modules will be a dependency for another project? I think in this case `package` is the only way to build it but I see how people IMO abuse the `install` goal. And I don't get why.

Is there any official considerations on how the multi-module project should be built?

UPD: I have only one explanation. Sometimes people just unaware of `-pl`, `-am` and `-rf` maven options. Thus it leads them to install the modules' artifacts into repository when they want to build part of the reactor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if none of the projects is a dependency of any other project you have a weird setup. why build them together if they don't belong together?

> Sometimes people just unaware of -pl,
>   -am and -rf maven options

in a normal setup, where there are dependencies between modules, these options (at least `-rf`) don't work if the modules aren't installed.

OK, you are using a dependency management system without dependencies. Yes, you can use `package` instead of `install`. But you are not avoiding bad usage patterns, you are either missing out on features or grouping things together that don't belong together.

Comment: I disagree about weirdness. It's very convenient to separate the functionality in modules. Or you can produce several standalone jars/wars (inside one multi-module project) which depend on common database module. And no other project depend on common module.

Comment: I agree that it's very convenient to separate the functionality of *related* projects in modules.But in Maven, Projects are related through the dependency mechanism.

Comment: I agree if we speak about transitive dependencies (http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Transitive_Dependencies). But Maven distinguishes transitive and your own dependencies. So, I doubt that the approach should be the same in both cases.